# Can an AirPort connected USB drive be used with Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, airport-extreme, time-capsule

I have a Time Capsule but the hard drive has failed. So basically it's now an AirPort Extreme. I'd like to connect a basic USB drive to the Time Capsule and use it for Time Capsule backup on two or more Macs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/132317/2008/02/timecapsule.html) claims to have done it (in 2008).

Comment: Thanks! I've come across various comments & postings online that **assume** it can be done but nothing to confirm it's possible until now.

Answer (score 0):

The June 2013 802.11ac model of the Extreme now officially support this.

From "Choosing a backup drive" in Apple's [Mac Basics: Time Machine backs up your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1427):

> Time Machine can only back up to a external drive connected to an AirPort Extreme 802.11ac base station. Time Machine cannot back up data to external drives connected to other AirPort Extreme base station models.

And [the printed manual](http://support.apple.com/manuals/#airport) states:

> **Using Time Machine with Your AirPort Extreme**
>
> If you connect a USB hard disk to your AirPort Extreme, you can use the Time Machine 
>   application to back up all your Mac computers, including your photos, music, movies, 
>   and documents.
>
> After you set up Time Machine, it automatically backs up your computer on a regular basis.
>   Use Time Machine preferences to set up automatic backups, use a different backup disk, or 
>   adjust other settings.
>
> To set up or adjust Time Machine on a computer using Mac OS X v10.5.7 or later:
>
> 1. Choose Apple > System Preferences, and then click Time Machine.
> 2. Slide the switch to ON.
> 3. Click Select Disk.
> 4. Choose your AirPort Extreme and click Use Disk.

(For those in doubt of replacing an Express with an Extreme: note that the latter does not support AirPlay! I noticed that just in time...)